# Continuity of the multiplicative inverse; $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $\Omega$ is a compact Hausdorff space.

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that if $f$ is continuous, then the multiplicative inverse $1/f$ (provided f is non-zero for any $x\in \Omega$) is also continuous? For some context, I am studying operator algebras, and without proof, my reference book said that for any $f\in C(\Omega),$ the spectrum $\sigma(f)$ is equal the image $f(\Omega).$ I think this is pretty easy to prove, if I can show that the multiplicative inverse of a continuous function is also continuous. Also, is the hypothesis that $\Omega$ is compact-Hausforff really necessary?

Comment: Yes, it's true, and it's as easy as showing that $z \mapsto z^{-1}$ is continuous on $\Bbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, and that compositions of continuous functions are continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $1/f = \xi f$ with $\xi : z \in \mathbb{C}^\times \mapsto \frac{1}{z} \in \mathbb{C}$. Since $\xi$ is continuous, so is $1/f$, regardless of the additional conditions on $\Omega$.

**Edit**: strictly speaking, one should say that $1/f = \xi \tilde{f}$ with $\tilde{f}$ the correstriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{C}^\times$ which exists (and is continuous) by hypothesis.

Comment: I see, then it is not really necessary that $\Omega$ is compact-Hausdorff?

Comment: Correct, it is not necessary at all. If $(X,\tau)$ is any topological space and $f : X \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and never vanishes, then $1/f$ exists and is continuous.

Comment: Well I'm guessing they want the domain topology to have nice properties at least then. Thank you.